# How to download an artifact in Azure DevOps artifacts

Tags: maven, azure-devops

Could someone tell me how to download an artifact in Azure DevOps through maven task?
I do not want to use universalpackages task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be able to  work with **Maven artifacts** in Azure Artifacts feeds.

Fist you need to set up your feed

[image]

Then you could run this command in your project directory to restore your package

```
mvn build
```

Run this command in your project directory to publish your package

```
mvn deploy
```

More details please refer our official doc here-- [Set up Azure Pipelines and Maven](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/maven?view=azure-devops)

---

**Update:**

You could use Rest API to achieve this. Refer to this doc first: [Maven - Download Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/maven/downloadpackage?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

```
GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feed name}/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}/{version}/{fileName}/content?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

To download this in script, you can use powershell task to achieve it:

```
$strURL = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feed name}/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}/{version}/{fileName}/content?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

$filePath="D:\"

$fileName=$filePath+"\build.{type}"

$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $strURL -Headers @{   

 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"

} -Method GET  -OutFile $fileName
```

Replace the relevant file type to specify it in the `$fileName=$filePath+"\build.{type}"`. After this script finished successfully, you can check your local file in the corresponding file path.

Comment: I know all of this.. Azure artifact has some artifact in its feed..Now I want to download it...the commands u have told is for publishing...I have already published ..I want to download those through maven

Comment: @priya [Maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops) is used to build your Java code. You could not simply download packages through this task. If you do not want touse universalpackages task. You could also use Rest API or powershell script to download Azure artifact and feed. Details please see my update reply